# Getting error when publishing the angular2 component on npm ,publish error :"Are you logged in as the correct user? : names"

Tags: angular, npm

I have a angular2 cli component and I want it to publish on npm.I have created user at npm.
I used the command **-- adduser**
but when I tried to publish I am getting  following error.

```
D:\names>npm publish
    npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 403
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "publi
    sh"
    npm ERR! node v6.9.2
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
    npm ERR! code E403

    npm ERR! you do not have permission to publish "names". Are you logged in as the correct user? : names
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
    npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     D:\names\npm-debug.log

    D:\names>sudo -s
    'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages).

You need to login at the client side:

```
npm login
```

and confirm your login with:

```
npm config ls
```

**Side note**: `sudo` is a linux command to get permissions which are otherwise unavailable to the user directly.Its equivalent in windows could be *run as administrator*